# Calculations and update results in Python data frames

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm a recent convert from excel to python. I think that what I'm trying to here would be traditionally done with a Vlookup of sorts. But I might be struggling with the terminology and not being able to find the python solution. I have been using the pandas library for most of my data analysis framework.

I have two different data frames. One with the weight changes (DF1), and other with the weights(DF2). I want to go line by line (changes are chronological) and:

1. create a new column in DF1 with the weight *before* the change
   (basically extracted from DF2).
2. update the results in DF2 where Weight = Weight + WeightChange

Note: The data frames do not  have the same dimension, an individual has several weight changes(DF1) but only one weight (DF2):

```
    Name  WeightChange 
1   John  5
2   Peter 10  
3   John  7  
4   Mary  -20  
5   Gary  -3
```

DF2:

```
    Name  Weight 
1   John  180
2   Peter 160   
3   Mary  120  
4   Gary  150
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) df1 and df2 on the 'Name' column to add the weight column to df1.

Then I'd [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html#pandas.Series.groupby) df1 on name and apply a [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to calculate the total weight change for each person. `transform` returns a Series aligned to the orig df so you can add an aggregated column back to the df.

Then I'd merge this column to df2 and then it's a simple case of adding this total weight change to the existing weight column:

```
In [242]:
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left')
df1['WeightChangeTotal'] = df1.groupby('Name')['WeightChange'].transform('sum')
df1

Out[242]:
    Name  WeightChange  Weight  WeightChangeTotal
0   John             5     180                 12
1  Peter            10     160                 10
2   John             7     180                 12
3   Mary           -20     120                -20
4   Gary            -3     150                 -3

In [243]:
df2 = df2.merge(df1[['Name','WeightChangeTotal']], on='Name')
df2

Out[243]:
    Name  Weight  WeightChangeTotal
0   John     180                 12
1   John     180                 12
2  Peter     160                 10
3   Mary     120                -20
4   Gary     150                 -3

In [244]:
df2['Weight'] = df2['Weight'] + df2['WeightChangeTotal']
df2

Out[244]:
    Name  Weight  WeightChangeTotal
0   John     192                 12
1   John     192                 12
2  Peter     170                 10
3   Mary     100                -20
4   Gary     147                 -3
```

**EDIT**

To address your desired behaviour for the 'WeightBefore' column:

```
In [267]:
df1['WeightBefore'] = df1['Weight']  + df1.groupby('Name')['WeightChange'].shift().cumsum().fillna(0)
df1

Out[267]:
    Name  WeightChange  Weight  WeightBefore
0   John             5     180           180
1  Peter            10     160           160
2   John             7     180           185
3   Mary           -20     120           120
4   Gary            -3     150           150
```

So the above groups on 'Name', applies a [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) to the column and then [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum) so we add the incremental differences, we have to call [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna) as this will produce `NaN` values where we have only a single weight change per Name.